# Pandas to spark data frame converts datetime datatype to bigint

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `pandas` data frame in `pyspark`. I want to create/load this data frame into a `hive` table.

```
pd_df = pandas data frame

id                    int64
TEST_TIME             datetime64[ns]
status_time           object
GROUP                 object
test_type             object
dtype: object

    id TEST_TIME            status_time                 GROUP       test_type

0   1 2017-03-12 02:19:51                                       Driver started
1   2 2017-03-12 02:19:53  2017-03-11 18:13:43.577   ALARM      AL_PT2334_L
2   3 2017-03-12 02:19:53  2017-03-11 18:13:43.577   ALARM      AL_Turb_CNet_Ch_A_Fault
3   4 2017-03-12 02:19:53  2017-03-11 18:13:43.577   ALARM      AL_Encl_Fire_Sys_Trouble
4   5 2017-03-12 02:19:54  2017-03-11 18:13:44.611  STATUS      ST_Engine_Turning_Mode
```

Now I converted the `pandas` data frame to spark data frame like below.

```
spark_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pd_df)


+---+-------------------+--------------------+------+--------------------+
| id|          TEST_TIME|         status_time| GROUP|           test_type|
+---+-------------------+--------------------+------+--------------------+
|  1|1489285191000000000|                    |      |      Driver started|
|  2|1489285193000000000|2017-03-11 18:13:...| ALARM|         AL_PT2334_L|
|  3|1489285193000000000|2017-03-11 18:13:...| ALARM|AL_Turb_CNet_Ch_A...|
|  4|1489285193000000000|2017-03-11 18:13:...| ALARM|AL_Encl_Fire_Sys_...|
|  5|1489285194000000000|2017-03-11 18:13:...|STATUS|ST_Engine_Turning...|
+---+-------------------+--------------------+------+--------------------+

DataFrame[id: bigint, TEST_TIME: bigint, status_time: string, GROUP: string, test_type: string]
```

I want the `TEST_TIME` column to be a timestamp column but I am getting `bigint`.

I want the `timestamp` to be exactly like in `pd_df` even in `spark_df`.

I have done like below while converting `pandas` dataframe to `spark` dataframe

```
spark_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pd_df).withColumn("TEST_TIME", (F.unix_timestamp("TEST_TIME") + 28800).cast('timestamp'))
```

I got below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1314, in withColumn
    return DataFrame(self._jdf.withColumn(colName, col._jc), self.sql_ctx)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 51, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'unixtimestamp(TEST_TIME,yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires (string or date or timestamp) type, however, 'TEST_TIME' is of bigint type.;"
```

How can I achieve what I want

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Convert your pandas dataframe column of type datetime64 to python datetime object, like this:
`pd_df['TEST_TIME'] = pandas.Series(pd_df['TEST_TIME'].dt.to_pydatetime(), dtype=object)`

And then create the spark dataframe as you were doing.

Comment: I like this answer and have used it a lot.  However, as far as I can tell it doesn't work if there are any null/NaN/NaT values in the pandas date time? I get errors like TimestampType can not accept object nan in type <class 'float'>

Answer (score 2):

Just convert it to the right range (from nanoseconds to seconds) and cast

```
df.withColumn(
  "TEST_TIME",
  (F.col("TEST_TIME") / F.pow(F.lit(1000), F.lit(3))).cast('timestamp'))
```

Comment: `py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.pow. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method pow([class java.lang.Double, class java.lang.Double]) does not exist` I got below error even after importing `pow` from `pyspark functions`

Comment: I find that when I use this method I get timezone issues? i.e. the datetimes created don't match those in the pandas dataframe, they are offset to server timezone. Any ideas?