# read parquet dataset in pyspark based on pandas DataFrame with datetime64 datatype

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

How to avoid `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Illegal Parquet type: INT64 (TIMESTAMP(NANOS,false))` when reading a Parquet dataset created from a pandas dataframe with a `datetime64[ns]` column.  Here is a minimal example -

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# pandas DataFrame with datetime64[ns] column
pdf = pd.DataFrame(data={'time': pd.date_range('10/1/23', '10/7/23', freq='D')})
pdf.to_parquet('<path>/data.parquet')

# read parquet dataset - creates Illegal Parquet type
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sdf = spark.read.parquet('<path>/data.parquet')

# recover original dataframe
df = sdf.toPandas()
```

The goal is read the parquet dataset and receive the `time` column as a pyspark `TimestampType`.

There are workarounds to convert the `datetime64[ns]` column to `object` datatype that are not ideal.  One such workaroud -
`pdf['time'] = pd.Series(pdf['time'].dt.to_pydatetime(), dtype=object)` - raises `FutureWarning: Passing unit-less datetime64 dtype to .astype is deprecated and will raise in a future version. Pass 'datetime64[ns]' instead` when coverting the spark dataframe back to pandas dataframe.

Running `pandas-1.5.3`, `pyspark-3.4.1` on Linux instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas to spark data frame converts datetime datatype to bigint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47958621/pandas-to-spark-data-frame-converts-datetime-datatype-to-bigint)

Comment: That's a workaround that triggers a deprecation-warning (see edit to question).

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula please see edit, I am running pandas 1.5.3 and pyspark 3.4.1 on a Linux instance (not azure databricks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Pandas stores `DatetimeIndex` under `datetime64[ns]` (nanoseconds), you must store datetime under `datetime64[ms]` (milliseconds) so that PySpark can correctly load the parquet file:

```
pdf.astype({'time': 'datetime64[ms]'}).to_parquet('<path>/data.parquet')

# Or use pd.date_range('10/1/23', '10/7/23', freq='D', unit='ms')  # <- unit
```

Output:

```
>>> sdf.show()
+-------------------+
|               time|
+-------------------+
|2023-10-01 00:00:00|
|2023-10-02 00:00:00|
|2023-10-03 00:00:00|
|2023-10-04 00:00:00|
|2023-10-05 00:00:00|
|2023-10-06 00:00:00|
|2023-10-07 00:00:00|
+-------------------+

>>> sdf.dtypes
[('time', 'timestamp_ntz')]
```

Comment: That leads to same issue in ```pandas < 2.0```.  It is a solution for ```pandas > 2.0```.